# Eclipse - display build path projects in project explorer

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

In the Eclipse IDE, using the Java Development Tools (JDT), you can add a Java project as a reference for another Java project by configuring the Java Build Path. Go to "Project > Properties > Java Build Path". Under the "Projects" tab, add the referenced project (assuming it is in the same workspace). How can I get projects referenced in this manner to show up in the Project Explorer (or even the Package Explorer or Navigator) view(s)? If, under the "Libraries" tab, you add a JAR or Library, it shows up under the "Referenced Libraries" node. Is it possible to do something similar with projects from the build path?

Thanks.

Comment: I think such is not allowed in Project Explorer of Eclipse. You can still check once in your [Filter menu](https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-27.htm) of your project explorer and make sure.